# Client validation doesn't fire on keyUp until after manual valid() call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the unobtrusive jQuery client side validation in MVC 3. I have a `[Required]` attribute on my model property. When I clear out the textbox on my form, it doesn't show the validation error. However if I manually call `document.forms['myform'].valid()`, and *then* clear out the textbox, it immediately shows the validation error.

It looks like the validation isn't hooking into the keyUp event until after `valid()` is manually called.

Any ideas on how to make this work without having to call `valid()` manually?

Comment: As I know it is an issue with unobtrusive/jquery validation plugin. It works and check values immediately after clicking submit button (or calling valid())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation triggers when you try to submit the form. Once you have clicked on the submit button it will work on blur. If you want to eagerly perform validation on blur without the need of submitting once you could use the following script:

```
$(function () {
    var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    settngs.onfocusout = function (element) { $(element).valid(); };
});
```

Comment: Probably also need to remove the `onfocusout` event handler after the form's `valid()` is called so that we don't end up with `valid()` being called twice when our fields blur. (Once by _our_ handler and once by the one jQuery validate will wire up for us.)